# Cancel Remote Notifications ,let it not show at the notification center

Tags: iphone

My app is close ,and screen is lock,when I receive a remote push notification,it appear on the screen,when I slide the notification but not slide the lock,it can open my app,all is OK.but  the  notification always  appear at  notification center,not disappear. How to dismiss it from the notification center,when I slide the notification.

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application{

  ```
        // put receive remote notification is here
  ```

  }

is there have some api like cancel localnotificationg,cancel remote notification?

Comment: are you implementing the delegates application:didReceiveLocalNotification: and application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:?

Comment: yes,but the two methods is my app is at background.but now my app is close

Comment: I think if you do not open the app it will not get discarded. It is expected behavior. Like when you see badge on iOS update, until you really upgrade it remains visible no matter how much you open the notification to see it is pending.

Comment: but i can open my app,it can also here,so i want to close it

Answer (score 0):

Set the applicationIconBadgeNumber property of your UIApplucation object to zero. This will clear tge notifications from notification center.

Comment: where i need to put the applicationIconBadgeNumber==0 ,i also put  at void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application{

       application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
}not useful

Answer (score 0):

Where you handle the notification, you need to reset applicationIconBadgeNumber property.

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
```

This should be ideally at the place of Custom Code in following snippet:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
NSLog(@"Received notification: %@", userInfo);
//[self addMessageFromRemoteNotification:userInfo];

NSString* alertValue = [[userInfo valueForKey:@"aps"] valueForKey:@"badge"];
NSLog(@"my message-- %@",alertValue);
badgeValue= [alertValue intValue];
[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber += badgeValue;   
//
//Custom Code where you actually respond to the notification. 
//
}
```

Comment: There is a section called iphone settings->Notifications. There, you can turn off/on notifications. Also you could turn off/on badges. Have you tried playing with these values for your app?

Comment: i want to cancel notification,i can receive it,and cancel it when my app at background.but when my app is close,i receive the notification,and slide it to open my app,the notification also is here

Comment: where do you see it after you open the app?